# jQuery slide changing with index and fadeout -- jumpiness

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a jQuery slideshow plugin.  One of my methods involves switching back and forth between pictures.  I have been pretty successful in creating it, here is an isolated case with the code thus far for the particular method:

```
var images = $("#simpleslides").children("img");

$(".slideButtons ul li").on("click", "a", function() {

        var anchorIndex = $(this).parent().index();
        var $activeSlide = $("#simpleslides img:visible");
        var $targetSlide = $(images[anchorIndex]);

        if($activeSlide.attr("src") == $targetSlide.attr("src") || $targetSlide.is(":animated")) {

            return false;

        } else {

            $activeSlide.css({ "z-index" : 0 });
            $targetSlide.css({ "z-index" : 1 });

            $targetSlide.stop().fadeIn("slow", function() {

                $activeSlide.hide();

            });

        }

    });
```

Here is a fiddle to see it in working action: http://jsfiddle.net/ase3E/

For the most part, this works as you would expect it to.  When a user clicks on the corresponding number, it fades in the picture.

However, I am running into some jumpiness and occasionally a complete `hide` of the slides when I am clicking around quickly.  If you play with the fiddle, you will see what I am referring to  Try clicking around on each image to see.

I have adopted `stop` which I thought would fix the problem but has not.  I have put the `hide` method after the `fadeIn` callback, but that has also not helped the situation.

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: ... sorry, where is the plugin?

Comment: I haven't put this into the plugin yet.  This is the isolated case, but works exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ase3E/3/)**</kbd> :)

```
var images = $("#simpleslides").find("img");
$(".slideButtons ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = $(this).index();
    images.eq(i).stop().fadeTo(500,1).siblings('img').fadeTo(500,0);
});
```